# (OpenERP 6.0.4) KeyError: 'id' When calling osv_memory wizard

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I'm having a little problem in OpenERP 6.0.4,
I want to call a wizard using python function,
but it keeps giving me this error :

> Environment Information : 
>   System : Windows-Vista-6.1.7601-SP1
>   OS Name : nt
>   Operating System Release : Vista
>   Operating System Version : 6.1.7601
>   Operating System Architecture : 32bit
>   Operating System Locale : en_US.cp1252
>   Python Version : 2.5.2
>   OpenERP-Client Version : 6.0.4
>   Last revision No. & ID :Bazaar Package not Found !Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "netsvc.pyo", line 489, in dispatch
>     File "service\web_services.pyo", line 599, in dispatch
>     File "osv\osv.pyo", line 122, in wrapper
>     File "osv\osv.pyo", line 176, in execute
>     File "osv\osv.pyo", line 167, in execute_cr
>     File "osv\orm.pyo", line 2946, in read
>     File "osv\orm.pyo", line 2946, in 
>   KeyError: 'id'

This is the wizard's class :

```
class mrp_bom_product(osv.osv_memory):
_name='mrp.bom.product'
_columns={
    'product_id':fields.many2one('product.product','Product')
}
mrp_bom_product()
```

This is the function that calls the wizard :

```
def copy(self, cr, uid, id, default={}, context=None):
     return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'mrp.bom.product',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'views': [(False, 'form')],
        'target': 'new',
     }
```

and this is the wizard's record in xml :

```
   <record id="mrp_bom_product_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">mrp.bom.product.view</field>
        <field name="model">mrp.bom.product</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Pick Product">
                <field name="product_id"/>
                <group colspan="4">
                    <button string="Cancel" special="cancel" icon="gtk-cancel"/>
                    <button string="Ok" name="saveproduct" type="object" icon="gtk-ok"/>
                </group>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record id="mrp_bom_product_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">mrp.bom.product.act</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">mrp.bom.product</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="target">new</field>
    </record>
```

Can you help me to figure out what is wrong with my code ?
really appreciate it ,thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

copy() is an inbuild openerp orm function which returns the id of the new record. So please change your function name.

Comment: I know,but I want to call the wizard before executing the copy function <br/>
I'm sorry,should've been more specific :)